# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. _Pnext было 0x6DD574

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

Делаю лабораторную работу по программированию и выскакивает ошибка.

[image: Ошибка]
Вот код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

struct int_double // в файл будем записывать пакеты
{
    string Country;
    int Days = 0;
    double Price = 0.0;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int_double pack; // пакет
    FILE* f; // переменная для работы с файлом
    int i; // счётчик

    string CoutryList[7] = { "Америка", "Шведция", "Австрия", "Китай", "Нидерланды", "Франция", "Германия" };
    int DaysList[7] = { 4, 5, 8, 3, 4, 7, 5 };
    double PriceList[7] = { 600.0, 300.0, 250.0, 500.0, 400.0, 250.0, 300.0 };

    f = fopen("C:\\Users\\KING\\Desktop\\tours.dat", "ab+");
/*
    else
    {
        f = fopen("C:\\Users\\KING\\Desktop\\tours.dat", "ab+");

        pack.Country = ""; // инициализация пакета
        pack.Days = 0;
        pack.Price = 0.0;
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) // запишем в файл в цикле 10 пакетов
        {
            pack.Country = CoutryList[i];
            pack.Days = DaysList[i];
            pack.Price = PriceList[i];
            fwrite(&pack, sizeof(int_double), 1, f); // записываем в файл f ровно 1 пакет pack размера int_double 
        }
    }
*/
    for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(int_double); i++)
    {
        fseek(f, i * sizeof(int_double), SEEK_SET); // перемещаемся от начала (SEEK_SET) файла f на 4 длинны пакета int_double, то есть к началу 5-го пакету
        fread(&pack, sizeof(int_double), 1, f); // считываем из файла f ровно 1 пакет pack размера int_double
        cout << "Страна: [" << pack.Country << "] Дни: [" << pack.Days << "] Цена: [" << pack.Price << "]" << endl;
    }
    fclose(f); // закрываем файл
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0; // возвращаем 0 - правило хорошего тона
}
```

На это ссылается в xmemory

```
// MEMBER FUNCTIONS FOR _Container_base12
inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all() noexcept {
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    if (_Myproxy) { // proxy allocated, drain it
        _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);

        for (auto _Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter; *_Pnext; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter) {
            (*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = nullptr;
        }

        _Myproxy->_Myfirstiter = nullptr;
    }
#endif // _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
}

В чём может быть проблема?
```

Comment: извините, я немного не в тему, но такой страны как **Шведция** пока не существовало

Comment: Это понятно, накидал от балды просто, что бы было.

Comment: В такой ситуации стоит заглянуть в окошко Стек вызовов и найти место в своем коде.